# JAI ClassNotFound Exception when calling JAI.create

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, image-processing, jai

I am trying to read a .tif image using javax.media.jai.JAI.  Here is my code:

```
import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;

BufferedImage image = null;
if(extension.toLowerCase().equals("tif")) {
    RenderedOp op = JAI.create(fileName, file);
    image = op.getAsBufferedImage();
} else {
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
}
```

The "file" (Java.io.File) and "fileName" (String) parameters are fine.  But when it gets to the "JAI.create(...)" line, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.JAI
```

I'm not sure why it can't find JAI.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JAI doesn't come with the JDK. You get it separately. Find the appropriate JAR library [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html). Then add that to your path.

*Note: If you are using Windows, you can get the jar and specify the path by yourself. Or get the exe which will install the same jar and add it to your system classpath. I would prefer to set the paths by myself.*

*On Ubuntu, you can also install it via*

```
sudo apt-get install libjai-core-java
```

Loading Image can be done like this:

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String filePath){
    RenderedOp img = JAI.create("fileload", filePath);
    return img.getAsBufferedImage();
}
```

`"fileload"`, as a literal String, is the **name of the operation** to load an image from a file using `JAI.create()`. That could also throw an exception if `fileName` is not equal to `"fileload"`.

Comment: is there a way to convert from a renderedImage to a bufferedImage?  I will need it to be a buffered image for another process

Comment: Still getting the same exception.  I am using eclipse and added jai_core.jar and jai_codec.jar to the build path, but that didn't work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Update your code sample with your code changes. That'll help us know what you've done.

Comment: @dmoss18 I just changed my code so that you get it as BufferedImage.